# Declaring self-referencing pointers in Swift

Tags: objective-c, pointers, swift, self

What would be the equivalent in swift of this Obj-C code?

I'm guessing something with CMutableVoidPointer

```
static void *CapturingStillImageContext = &CapturingStillImageContext;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
var CapturingStillImageContext: COpaquePointer = nil
withUnsafePointer(&CapturingStillImageContext) {
    CapturingStillImageContext = COpaquePointer($0) }
```

Answer (score 3):

`CMutableVoidPointer` isn't available anymore as of Beta 3. Theres `UnsafePointer` and `ConstUnsafePointer` - you can declare it this way:

```
let CapturingStillImageContext = UnsafePointer<()>()
```

Comment: That answers it, many thanks.

Comment: This would simply create a nil pointer - but not a pointer initialized with a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this technique, but it would be nice to find a more elegant solution:

```
var SelfReferencingKey = initialize_SelfReferencingKey()

func initialize_SelfReferencingKey() -> UnsafePointer<()> {
    return withUnsafePointer(&SelfReferencingKey, { UnsafePointer($0) } )
}
```